# for /f %%I was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a script to copy the latest file.
I got this command from the net:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "X:\Dirs\*.rar" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I 
copy "%NewestFile%" "J:\Personal\Gastos\dirs"
```

It outputs an error:

> %%I was unexpected at this time.

Does anyone know why that happens and how to correct it?

Thanks

Jeraisel

Comment: are you executing this directly in the command prompt or it's in a batch file?

Comment: Use `%I` when you run your code in command prompt and `%%I` in batch files, according to the help (type `for /?` into a command prompt window)...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The command ran but no files where copied

Comment: sure, there *is*  a source file and the destination path * does*  exist?

Comment: Yes, the paths are cp paste from explorer window. And I just cp pasted on the command line and it went to the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a batch file:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
(SET SrcDir=X:\Dirs)
IF /I "%CD%" NEQ "%SrcDir%" PUSHD "%SrcDir%"
SET "NewestFile="
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('DIR/B/OD *.rar') DO SET "NewestFile=%%I"
IF DEFINED NewestFile (IF EXIST "J:\Personal\Gastos\dirs\" (
        COPY "%NewestFile%" "J:\Personal\Gastos\dirs"))
```

Comment: Thanks The output is The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: try `... IN ('DIR/B/OD "X:\Dirs*.rar" 2^>nul') DO ...` to disregard "file not found" error.

Comment: Script has been updated to reflect that, please ensure your source directory is correctly placed within the parentheses on line 2.

Comment: The file not found error is gone now it's The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: And no files are copyed

Comment: Change `@ECHO` to **ON** and add a new line to the bottom containing only `PAUSE`. Run the file again and paste the console output somewhere for use to see. **EDIT** Code changed again due to source file and path change from `X:\Dirs*.rar` to `X:\Dirs\*.rar`.

Comment: I tried it again and now it copied all the files not just the most recent

Comment: I was looking in the source directory. It worked, Thanks

Comment: Please mark the question as correctly answered, it helps the site, future visitors and my poor self-esteem.